# Concatenating the output of a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, concatenation, index-error

```
Y= zeros(3, 354)
    for m = 1 : 118
        R=GridData.R2(:,3*m-2:3*m);
        X=GridData.X2(:,3*m-2:3*m);
        B=GridData.B1(:,3*m-2:3*m);
        G=GridData.G1(:,3*m-2:3*m);
        Y(:,m)= R+ 1j*X;
        m=m+1;
    end
```

This is the error: Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 3). I would like to concatenate the output from a for loop.

Comment: `R` and `X` have 3 columns, and you put `R + 1j*X` which has also 3 columns into a single column of `Y`. What does `B` and `G` do here? Why do you write `m = m+1`? The loop counter of a `for` loop advances automatically. Please add a MWE; a code that people can copy paste and run on their machines and put 3 back-tics above and below code segments, like ``` ... code ...```.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace, into your post. And read [mre], it is important that we know what each of the variables are, so that we can reproduce the problem, otherwise it can be really hard to understand what is going on. In your case, I would guess that the error doesn't happen in the assignment, but in indexing into `GridData.R2` or one of the other fields.